# getting error in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am getting the following error in my joomla site, pleas help

PHP Warning:  session_start() [function.session-start]: Node no longer exists in D:\Domains\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com\www\libraries\joomla\session\session.php on line 423
PHP Warning:  session_write_close() [function.session-write-close]: Node no longer exists in D:\Domains\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com\www\libraries\joomla\session\session.php on line 562

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of session write path error in your php.ini
You should ask your host to fix the session write path.